# Copying Windows Service to Server

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll, service

At the moment I have a Windows Service and App (Desktop Tray Win Form App with Stop/Start buttons to stop the service and a PING to check the 3rd party API it uses it working and obtain the current balance - It's a Betfair Betting app)

At the moment I am running this off my Win 7 64 bit Desktop but we are moving to a dedicated server Win 2012.

Both the Win Service/Form are in the same project and they reference a DLL which I made that has all the code inside (connects to the DB, 3rd party Betfair API, gets runner/winner info, renews session info etc).

The Windows Server does NOT have Visual Studio on it.

Can I just copy my DLL up to the server, put it in Windows/System32 and Regsvr register it and then copy the .EXE for my Form and Service up to the server?

Also without having the VS Toolset to register a Win Service on a machine what commands do I need to run to install the Windows Service on the Server.

These are 2 distinct solutions, one with the DLL code, one with the Service Project and Win Form Project.

I just want to know the best/quickest/easiest/proper way of getting it to work on the new server without having VS on it to register the service.

Can I just copy the code up to a folder (should it go in a specific folder on the server - the log files are piped out into it's own sub folder of /programdata) and run  installutil [PATH TO EXE] to install the Service or is there something more I need to do.

As there are two solutions I can't (or don't know how to) create a deployment package with all the right links and references in across solutions.

However should it be more complicated than..
-Copy DLL to System32
-Regsvr my DLL
-Build the service/win form project on my computer then copy the .EXEs up somewhere
-Run installutil [PATH TO EXE] to register the service
-Double click the windows form to open it (should auto start on reboot and sit in desktop tray)

All in .NET 4.5, Was built in vs 2012, 64 bit, C#

### Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Creating a deployment package is the better option, but, because it's not a option for you, the `regsvr32` and `installutil` option should do the job.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So are you saying that I should do exactly what I laid out, e.g regsvr32 the DLL then copy up the EXE and run the installutil to create the window service. WilI need special permissions or any other command line prompts to be run to get this working. And where is the best place to store these EXE files as on my PC they are in My Document/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/... etc, does it matter or can I put them anywhere>?

Comment: You should place everything in a folder under "Program Files". Regarding permissions, you'll might need to run `cmd` with administrative privileges (using **Run as administrator**). A deployment package would have saved you all of these little steps to get your application up and running.

Comment: ill look into creating one

Comment: When trying to register my DLL (code I wrote), on the server I get the "Api-ng-sample-code.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Its a valid DLL, I load it into my service/app - does it need to be registered with regsvr32.exe or from what I am reading on the net it seems that not all DLLs have to be registered before use?

Comment: If it's a .Net assembly DLL then you don't need to register it.

Comment: Should they still reside in System32 or just in the folder along with the app/service?

Comment: Same folder as the app should be fine.